# SQL Server database mirror server cannot be reached

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, mirroring

I can ping and telnet both servers but getting this error :

> The server network address "TCP://MyPrincipalServerIp:5022" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QR3c.jpg)

I have added login with same name and password on both servers.

Both SQL Server instances are Enterprise edition.

I have granted all permissions to both logins and sysadmin role to them.
Mirror db is restored with no recovery mode with full mode and then with transaction log.

Mirror db is in restoring state and after trying mirroring and getting this error, it turns to recovering state but is not mirrored.

I have added rules for port 5022 in and out firewall rules in both servers.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you check ERRORLOG on both sides to see if you have any useful information in there?

Comment: where is these errorlog?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio you can find it under Management > SQL Server Logs

Comment: On the file system, it can be found at %Program-Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG